# Using Alias While Concating Columns And Running Query Through A Java Program

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I want to concat two columns and use an alias for the columns while querying.
The query is something like this:

```
     select distinct T1.*,
 T1.FieldA || ',' || FieldB  from table1 T1 
 join ( select FieldA || ',' || FieldB as criteria from table2 where 
 create_dateTime >= to_timestamp('10-NOV-14 01.01.01.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') and 
 create_dateTime <= to_timestamp('19-NOV-14 01.01.01.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')) 
 T2 on (T1.FieldA || ',' || FieldB = T2.criteria) ORDER BY T1.FieldA || ',' || FieldB;
```

This query works for me in Oracle. Would it work in MYSQL, MS SQL, DB2 as well ?

Is there anyother way of writing this query ?

Comment: You will need to process the datetime fields in a MySQL way (ie, not using to_timestamp), and in mysql you use the CONCAT function to concatenate fields. Further you would probably be better doing the join on the FieldA and FieldB fields, rather than concatenating them together for the join, and the sub query does not seem necessary (MySQL will not carry through any indexs from the sub query to use to do any joins).

Answer (score 1):

You want to translate this Oracle query to MySQL.   First, let's try to optimize it overall.  You're joining on a computed field (computed by concatenation). That's bound to be slow.  Why not simply join on the fields in the concatenation, like so:

```
from table1 T1 
join table2 T2 ON T1.FieldA = T2.FieldA AND T1.FieldB = T2.FieldB
```

Now, there may be some complex data-dependent reason this won't work. But I seriously doubt it.

Second, you're using ordinary (INNER) JOIN, so there's no need for the timestamp selection to appear in a subquery.  That means your Oracle-specific query can be refactored like this. This is a *lot* simpler for your dbms to handle.

```
select distinct
      T1.*,
      T1.FieldA || ',' || T1.FieldB  AS criteria
 from table1 T1 
 join table2 T2  ON T1.FieldA = T2.FieldA AND T1.FieldB = T2.FieldB
where T2.create_dateTime >= 
           to_timestamp('10-NOV-14 01.01.01.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
  and T2.create_dateTime <=
          to_timestamp('19-NOV-14 01.01.01.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
ORDER BY T1.FieldA || ',' || T1.FieldB;
```

Try this in your Oracle system. You may be happy at the performance improvement.

Finally, you need to change your concatenations and date processing to be MySQL specific. That's easy enough.

```
select distinct
      T1.*,
      CONCAT(T1.FieldA, ',', T1.FieldB)  AS criteria
 from table1 T1 
 join table2 T2  ON T1.FieldA = T2.FieldA AND T1.FieldB = T2.FieldB
where T2.create_dateTime >= '2014-11-10 13:01:01'
  and T2.create_dateTime <= '2014-11-19 13:01:01'
ORDER BY CONCAT(T1.FieldA, ',', T1.FieldB);
```